# How to input lat long to a program comment line from a file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a program, to run the program I have to give latitude and longitude at the terminal as given below:

```sh
$ access_litho -p lat long
```

I stored all lat long in a file as given below:

```
-7.4201 41
-7.3201 46
-7.4201 43
-7.2201 45
-7.8201 47
-7.7201 43
```

I have tried the below code:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
access_litho  -p input_file.txt << EOF
EOF
```

but it's showing error:

> "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: `while read -r lat lon || [ -n "$lon" ]; do access_litho -p "$lat" "$lon"; done < file`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin could you please explain each argument in code

Comment: @rehman see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001  to understand how a while read loop works.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, what is the `|| [ -n "$lon" ]` for?

Comment: To handle a non-POSIX end-of-file with no `'\n'` character. If you simply use, `while read -r line do; ..` you will skip the last line of data in that circumstance, because no `'\n'` is seen. The `lat` and `lon` variable will have been filled, so by adding the check `[ -n "$lon" ]` you are testing if `lon`, the last variable in your list was filled (which ensure all prior variable, e.g. `lat` were also filled) in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
while read lat lon; do
  access_litho -p "$lat" "$lon";
done < coordinates.txt
```

We use a `while` loop that will read 2 inputs from the standard input, using the `read` command, `lat` and `lon`. The `read` command is smart enough to recognize 2 inputs on 1 line because they are separated by whitespace.

Then, for every `read` operation, we execute `access_litho -p "$lat" "$lon"`.

To make the script read your input, we pass the filename at the end of the `while` loop, using the `<` character: `< coordinates.txt`.

Comment: how to insert a blank line in an output file after the execution of  very lat  long

Comment: You can just add `echo "" >> filename`